# Empty space above ImageView

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, listview, imageview

I got a static ImageView above a listView. 
But the imageView is showing some empty space above it.

How can i remove this empty space?

-when i use the the image as background of a TextView its perfectly alligned at parent top

Here is my xml for the ImageView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
>

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titlebartear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/titlebartear"
        />

 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:paddingTop="0px" 
    android:tag="fileslist"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:divider="@color/pijndagboek_light_blue"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_below="@id/titlebartear"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you experimented with android:scaleType parameters? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType ; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Can you post all of your .xml file for this intent? (normally its main.xml, but you might have changed that.) The problem might be somewhere else in the file.

Comment: this is all of the layout @JamesWright

Comment: Thanks. Im not on ym laptop atm, but a school computer so i cant copy this into eclipse and mess with it to fix it. i presume you added in the laout_marginTop property to try and fix it?

Comment: thnx! without marginTop it shows me the emty space.. @JamesWright

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but may help others that stubmle across this:

**"Adjust ViewBounds"** worked for me, when a drawable automatically scales the height of the View it's set to. (Resulting in empty space above and below the image itself)

Answer (score 0):

set your image as background to your Imageview.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titlebartear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/titlebartear"
        />
```

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of using an ImageView, though.

Comment: The space is coming because your original image may have that space

Comment: ye my image is shown correctly when i use it as a background. But i already found a solution by setting the marginTop on -5dip (still strange)

Comment: Nope the original image dont have that emty space (@VenkataKrishna)

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"

worked :S