# How do I remove extra space above and below imageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I have a really simple image within a `RelativeLayout` and for some reason I am getting extra spacing on the top and bottom which I can't remove. How can I clear it out?

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Image from Eclipse preview]

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/slice11pp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Try this

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: in my code this work only with 'android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"'

Answer (score 10):

In your above `imageView` just add `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: change it to ´android:scaleType="fitXY"´

Comment: This will alter the aspect ratio and make things look stretched or squished.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is probably that you have no scale type set... Add it to the XML for the ImageView, "fitCenter" should be correct, but there are others, check: [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/slice11pp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Comment: In my case, I also needed to set android:adjustViewBounds="true", as its explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701685/empty-space-above-imageview?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Must be enough adding the property:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

for example:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/slice11pp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **drawable-nodpi** folder if there is no specific requirement for images. Then `android: adjustViewBounds = "true"` acts as the default.

If you use **drawable-nodpi** you don't need to set `android:adjustViewBounds = "true"`.

I think this is the most effortless method.

Answer (score 3):

this line of code will solve the problem

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

don't forget to rotate the image

Comment: This has been answered years before!

Answer (score 2):

If your image view height is match_parent, even if you set android:adjustViewBounds="true" ImageView will add some extra blank space at top and bottom side. so, change ImageView height to wrap_content and set android:adjustViewBounds="true"

for example

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/img_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: this actually increased the space LOL

Answer (score 2):

android:scaleType="centerCrop" by adding this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/temp_image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

works for me Before and After Image
[image: Before and After Image]

Answer (score 0):

just add ScaleType="fitxy" inside the Image view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ImageView
     (...)
     android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the perfect solution

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

it will not leave any extra single dp in any side. however the image will be distorted if it is not portrait image.