# Removing space above and below ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

Hello I need help as i Am **adding an ImageView in my android xml** file and i get an **extra space above and below it** i have tried to see the options that i can use to remove it one of them was adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
but **when i do that that it removes my action Bar completely below is my code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fred.yebo.MainFragment">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/yeboAdd"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/dice"

      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" but it can make your image stretch.

Comment: It doesn't work it stretches the image and loose the resolution

Comment: there are normally two solutions for this first is fitXy which will stretch your image and second is you should use wrap_content width instead of match parent

Comment: I changed the codes to wrap_content and still the image doent look fine @VivekMishra

Comment: you can't make it look fine unless you hardcode image width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this attribute :

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

automatically scales the height of the View.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fred.yebo.MainFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/yeboAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967611/why-do-i-get-white-space-on-top-and-on-the-bottom-of-my-imageview-in-my-relative).

Comment: I have tried This but it removes the bar and the image place itself at the top

Comment: you might be doing something wrong otherwise this is working fine. what problem you are facing now ?

Comment: The Problem That i face is that applying `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` removes the top bar

Comment: have you check mentioned link in my answer ? @user3551487

Comment: that is correct approach. when you resize image it will be solved after adding this attributes to imageview.

Comment: inform me if still having issues. @user3551487

Comment: what was problem with this answer ? @user3551487

Answer (score 0):

You can try with scaleType property of your imageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

this line scale your image with size of your container.There are a few properties of scaleType you can try which will be better for your case.Hope to help you!

Comment: i think you must set some values to width and height to your imageview or at least set width to wrap_content, because the way you do this the image can`t look fine and will be stretch.

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fred.piku.MainFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pikuAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dice" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it stretches the image and loose it resolution @Hiren Patel

Comment: @user3551487, what happen ?

Comment: makes the top bar disappear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105782/discussion-between-hiren-patel-and-user3551487).