# Image is not fitting on whole screen for tablet

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-framelayout

I want to set the background to LinearLayout , I took reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967611/why-do-i-get-white-space-on-top-and-on-the-bottom-of-my-imageview-in-my-relative). But still it lefts spaces to 4 sides. screen shot is [image: screenshot]

Code is the following

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
<someviews></someviews>
 </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Please give some solution if any.

Comment: set **android:background="@mipmap/background"**  image to your **`LinearLayout`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [**`android:src`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src) instead of **`android:background`**.
- Add **`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`**

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

**Finally**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but still giving the same output

Comment: @KiranS Your image too small.

Comment: @KiranS call your image from `DRAWABLE` folder instead of `MIPMAP`

Comment: @KiranS call `android:src="@drawable/`

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>

<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

check dimen.xml file put 0dp  horizontal and vertical margin