# ImageView disappeared from Design view of content_man.xml

Tags: android, imageview

I tried to simply remove the whitespace of an image using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142780/how-do-i-remove-extra-space-above-and-below-imageview), but now it made the image disappear from the design view.
However, when I run the app in an emulator, it displays the image just fine.

How can I make the ImageView appear again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebuilding the project and refreshing the design view. If this doesn't work, restarting Android Studio may help.